# Using Linq(?) to get a property from a list inside of a list

Tags: c#, linq, list, select, lambda

I need help to select all Titles from List"FeedItem" that is inside of List"Feed" where Feed.Name matches a string from a combobox.

Below is my attempt, which is not succesful, might be on the wrong road.

```
 var loadFeedData = fillFeed.GetAllFeeds();
            var filteredOrders =
            loadFeedData.SelectMany(x => x.Items)
                 .Select(y => y.Title)
                 .Where(z => z.Contains(flow)).ToList();
```

To understand things better I'll post the Feed.cs code as well.

```
public class Feed : IEntity
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Namn { get; set; }
    public string UppdateInterval { get; set; }       
    public List<FeedItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Whole Code that I'm trying to get working, filling a ListView with the Title, based on the Name of the Listview with Feed.Name that I select.

```
private void listFlow_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listInfo.Items.Clear();
        listEpisode.Items.Clear();
        if (listFlow.SelectedItem != null)
        {

            string flow = listFlow.SelectedItem.ToString();
            var loadFeedData = fillFeed.GetAllFeeds();
            var filteredOrders = loadFeedData
.Where(f => f.Name == myStringFromComboBox)
.SelectMany(f => f.Items)
.Select(fi => fi.Title);

            listEpisode.Items.Add(filteredOrders);

        }
    }
```

- Posted whole code to clear out some ??

Comment: It would be useful to know the definition of `FeedItem`.

Comment: @cslecours no, isn't one property of Title enough?

Comment: What is `flow`, and why are you checking if the title contains `flow`?

Comment: Why is it not successful?

Comment: @Vladimirs, I don't want to have to assume anything about the Title property.

Comment: Check Main post for answer

Answer (score 9):

```
loadFeedData
    .Where(f => f.Name == myStringFromComboBox)
    .SelectMany(f => f.Items)
    .Select(fi => fi.Title);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for:

```
List<string> titles = loadFeedData.Where(f => f.Name == "SomeName")
                    .SelectMany(f => f.Items.Select(subItem => subItem.Title))
                    .ToList();
```

- First you will filter your main list `loadFeedData` based on Name
- Then select `Title` from `List<FeedItem>`
- Later flatten your *Titles*, using `SelectMany` to return an `IEnumerable<string>`
- *Optional,* call `ToList` to get a `List<string>` back.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use this one:

```
var filteredOrders = loadFeedData.Where(x => x.Name == flow)
                                 .SelectMany(x => x.Items)
                                 .Select(x => x.Title).ToList();
```

This will give you all FeedItem items inside all Feed things, which have Feed.Name == flow.

Comment: I guess he is trying to select Titles.

Comment: yep, let's assume that FeedItem also has a "Title" field :)

Comment: @Christian it indeed does.